# Extract URL data from XMLHttpRequest

Tags: javascript, php

here is my javaScript code:

```
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    var submitimages = document.getElementById('submitimages');
        submitimages.addEventListener('click', upload);

    var images = document.getElementById('images'); 
});

    var upload = function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            event.stopPropagation();

            var data = new FormData();

                for(var i = 0; i < images.files.length; ++i) {
                    data.append('images[]', images.files[i]);
                }

                var xhr = XMLHttpRequest();
                    xhr.open('POST', 'upload.php?test=' + 'test', true);
                    xhr.send(data);
    }
```

My objective is to upload multiple images using form data and I want those sent images to move on a different directory depending on text that is on the url **upload.php?test=' + 'test'** where as on my example I want to move those image to **test** folder

and here is my php code so far

[image]

Please help I tried everything I know but I think I need idea whos someone is more knowledgeable to JavaScript. Regards

Comment: Can you copy the PHP, screenshots are a pain.

Comment: the text editor is not accepting my code so I decided to printscreen it

Comment: I am assuming that you are passing array of images.
So foreach should be like:
foreach($_POST['images'] as $key => $value) {
 move_uploaded_file($value['images']['tmp_name'], 'images/'.$_POST['test'].$key.'.jpg');
}

Comment: @Rohit I tried your suggestion but nothing appears on a directory

Comment: Check directory permissions

Comment: still nothing happens